# How to set shell upper tabs to take full width

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm using Xamarin.forms 5.0 and `Shell`.

My XAML code is

```
<TabBar Route="Root">
    <Tab x:Name="NewsListPageTab" Title="News" Route="NewsListPage">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular}" Glyph="{x:Static utils:FontAwesomeIcons.Newspaper}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NewsListPage}" Title="News1">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular}"
                Glyph="{x:Static utils:FontAwesomeIcons.BadgePercent}">
                </FontImageSource>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NewsListPage}" Title="News2">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{StaticResource FaRegular}"
                Glyph="{x:Static utils:FontAwesomeIcons.BadgePercent}">
                </FontImageSource>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The overall appearance that I'm trying to create is like this image.

[image]

How is it possible to add icons to the inner tabs and make them full width in the app shell, please?

Comment: you probably need a custom renderer for that

Comment: Yes, I agree. Do you know how to implement the custom renderer, please?

Comment: I found an easy solution: instead of using ShellContent for upper tabs, we can use TabbedPages with pages representing the tabs we need.

Comment: In that case you won't be using Shell are you? You could provide your solution as an answer for others asking this same question.

Comment: I'm using shell for the lower tabbar, but for the upper tabs, I used TabbedPage for upper tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution: instead of using ShellContent for upper tabs, we can use TabbedPages with pages representing the tabs we need.

```
<Tab Title="ُShop" Route="CompaniesTabs">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate retailer:CompaniesTabs}" />
</Tab>
```

The TabbedPage code is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Retailer.CompaniesTabs">

    <retailer:CompaniesStatusPage Title="Store1" />
    <retailer:CompaniesListPage Title="Store3" />
    <retailer:CompaniesFavoritePage Title="Store3" />

</TabbedPage>
```

That's it.